# Как подключиться к сокету? если 1 адресс не рабочий

Tags: java, android, сокет

Как подключиться к сокету? если 1 адресс не рабочий

Весь код в сервисе

```
Socket socket = null;
            try {
                socket = new Socket("188.244.144.211", 49111);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                socket = new Socket("188.244.144.212", 49111);
            }
```

Все равно не работает, программа на андроиде работает и не вылетает, но и коонекта нет.

Как сделать так чтобы подключиться к 1 ip если коннекта нет то подключиться ко 2?

Удиительно то что даже я не могу проверить работает ли сервер с данным IP сейчас. Дебаг тоже не помогает НАРОД ПОМОГИТЕ!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего дело в тайм-ауте, по умолчанию он может быть очень долгим и Exception не появится до тех пор пока не произойдет разрыв по этой причине. Лучше попробовать подключаться к сокету другим способом, явно указывая тайм-аут, например вот тут это 10 секунд:

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Socket socket = new Socket();
            SocketAddress sockaddr = null;
            try {
                sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress("188.244.144.211", 49111);
                socket = new Socket();
                socket.connect(sockaddr, 10000);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                try {
                    sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress("188.244.144.212", 49111);
                    socket = new Socket();
                    socket.connect(sockaddr, 10000);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            } finally {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
```